# Can I par-bake this pot pie recipe?

Tags: baking, pot-pie

Once a week I gather with friends for an evening of gaming; trying to cut back on fast-food, I'm looking for a recipe I can make ahead and heat up in their oven while we play. I found a pot pie recipe that looks tasty and can be frozen [here](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-and-freeze-individ-140279); however, it bakes for an hour. Can I do anything to reduce this time? Or would a different type of meat pie work better: pasties, shepherd's/cottage pies, et cetera?

[This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15583/can-i-partially-bake-a-pie) is similar but seems to be dealing specifically with fruit pies, whereas I'm looking at meat pies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you don't defrost the pie before baking in the recipe so some of the time in the oven would just be defrosting the pie; so this could be done in advance by bringing it out of the freezer an hour and a half before baking say. As the chicken is already cooked it looks like all you're doing is cooking the pastry so you could just use thinner pastry which would cook quicker, or better you could use layers of phyllo  pasty which would cook a lot quicker but of course wouldn't puff up like the puff pastry.

If you follow this it could probably bake for just 25 minutes or there about.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That might work well considering it's about a 45 minute drive to their place, so I just have to remember to take it out maybe 30-40 minutes before leaving

Comment: Phylo in this case won't be made into a shell (would be too dry), but would be layered with filling like lasagne. And it will still need its time in the oven until the heat reaches the middle layers. So, while it can make for a tasty pie, I wouldn't say it will have a significant effect on baking time.

Comment: Really?  I've got a particularly good recipe for chicken pot pie with phylo and if you look at this google search you can see that it's not alone:  (http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pot+pie+recipe+%2Bfilo)